# Can i run databricks notebook cell on if condition... If true run all cell if false run only bottom 5 cells

Tags: databricks, azure-notebooks

I want combine my 2 different notebooks and add one condition on received parameter.
If parameter is True then run all cell of that notebook and if parameter is false only run added code from another notebooks that will be few bottom cells.

Basically i want to reduce the loading time of two notebook so combining them to one

```
 dbutils.widgets.text("condition", "True", "Condition: (True or False)") 
condition_str = dbutils.widgets.get("condition") condition = condition_str.lower() == "true"
def run_cell(cell_id):   dbutils.notebook.run(f"/FullNotebookPath", timeout_seconds=0, arguments={"cell_id": cell_id})

If condition:

for cell_number in range(1, 11):   run_cell(cell_number)

else: 

For cell_number in range(6, 11): run_cell(cell_number)
```

But the execution is failing.. Its working if i run single cell without for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your work in my environment.

Add required code in the main notebook as below.

**cell 1**

```
dbutils.widgets.text("cell_id", "1")
cell_no = dbutils.widgets.get("cell_id")
```

**cell 2**

```
dbutils.notebook.exit(f"Hi from cell {cell_no}")
```

**cell 3**

```
dbutils.notebook.exit(f"Hi from cell {cell_no}")
```

**cell 4**

```
dbutils.notebook.exit(f"Hi from cell {cell_no}")
```

[image]

Like this add your code to the corresponding cells, and call
your notebook in for loop with `cell_id` as argument.

```
dbutils.widgets.text("condition", "True", "Condition: (True or False)")
condition_str = dbutils.widgets.get("condition")
condition = condition_str.lower() == "true"

def run_cell(cell_id):
    return_values.append(
        dbutils.notebook.run(path, timeout_seconds=0, arguments={"cell_id": cell_id})
        )
```

Output:

[image]

```
return_values = []
if condition:
    for cell_number in  range(2, 7):
        run_cell(cell_number)
else:
    for cell_number in  range(5, 7):
        run_cell(cell_number)
        
print(return_values)
```

[image]

What your given is working fine. So, try to debug it.